# hadoop : 1 map multiple reducers with each reducer having different functionality? possible?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Here is an example:

Is it possible to have same mapper run against multiple reducers at the same time? like

```
map output : {1:[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2], 4:[5,4,6,7,8,9,5,3,3,2], 3:[1,5,4,3,5,6,7,8,9,1], so on}  

reducer1 : sum of all numbers  
reducer2 : average of all numbers  
reducer3 : mode of all numbers   

act on the the same key like  

reducer1 output: {1:sum of values, 2:sum of values, and so on}  
reducer2 output: {1:avg of values, 2: avg of values and so on}
reducer3 output: {1:mode of values, 2: mode of values, and so on}
```

and so on..Please let me know.

Comment: Very good question actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really wanted to answer this for you but it's already been asked. [Hadoop one Map and multiple Reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333618/hadoop-one-map-and-multiple-reduce)

Comment: changed the question based on the link you provided, I want to use same keys

Comment: @daydreamer Even though you slightly altered your question, the answer is still the same. You might want to see if you can use 'remote' jobs to do some calculations that then get reduced differently.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. But you can implement your own reducer that will calculate all the stuff for you and output it.

You can make an custom writable for that.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/04/simple-moving-average-secondary-sort-and-mapreduce-part-3/

This actually does pretty much what you are looking for.

Comment: This link is now dead